# Wordpress: How to edit all similar code with one click?

Tags: html, wordpress, performance, web

I have a website built with wordpress. Its a big website with 1000 pages. Sometimes i need to edit a link that is repeated in maybe 50 posts. Is there a way (probably with a plugin) to edit all similar links/code? 
I realise i could use a redirection plugin but i feel that would get messy after a while.

Usually its a link that needs updating/correcting but it would be useful to hae a way to modify all similar strings of code too.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Very good plugin: [Search & Replace | WordPress.org](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/); I also used this script that I think is mentioned in the answer below: [Database Search and Replace Script in PHP | interconnect/it](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). Please note that your question is off-topic and if you repeatedly ask poorly received questions, you may lose the ability to post new questions. Check the guides [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Many thanks for your advice. i did read the guide on how to ask a question here. I guess the question was well put together and was coding related but it would have been better answered in a wordpress forum. But your answer was very helpful in terms of helping the person with the question.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way to change link or text on all post is to do it on the database. You could use "PHPMyAdmin script for Search and Replace in Database".